# Como pegar conteúdo dentro de string até um caracter "barra /"

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte String:

```
$link = '13542345/essa_e_minhastring';
```

Como faço para pegar somente o valor ate a barra "/" e ignorar o resto ?

Eu gostaria de atribuir este valor a uma variável.

Estou usando o seguinte código, mas ele apenas quebra a string...e não separa em uma variável como eu preciso:

```
 $cod = str_replace("/","<br>",$link);
 echo $cod;
```

**O resultado é:**

> 13542345
>   essa_e_minhastring

Eu preciso que seja apenas:

> 13542345

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Podes partir a string pelo `/` usando o [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) e depois usar só a primeira parte assim:

```
$partes = explode("/", $link);
echo $partes[0]; // dá 13542345
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/oAnXfR

Outra alternativa é [usar regex](https://regex101.com/r/aR8cJ2/1) assim:

```
$link = '13542345/essa_e_minhastring';
$pattern = '/[^\/]+/';
preg_match($pattern, $link, $partes, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $partes[0][0]; // dá 13542345
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/4GGZbY

---

---

Fiz um [teste entre `explode`, `preg_match`, `strtok` e `substr`](https://ideone.com/czHgSW). O teste peca certamente por ser tão simples e isolado, e por isso não real. Mas é interessante. O resultado entre os 4 métodos é:

```
7.9003810882568E-8 sec / por explode
2.0149707794189E-7 sec / por preg_match // <- mais rápida
4.8128128051758E-8 sec / por strtok
5.2464962005615E-8 sec / por substr
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, caiu como uma luva.

Comment: E se eu quiser dar um `explode` no `value` de um `array` ?
Ele retorna um erro informando que ele espera uma `string` e recebeu um `array`, como proceder nesse caso??

Comment: @MarcosHenzel `explode` trabalha sobre strings somente.

Answer (score 14):

A função [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), quebra uma string por um delimitador e retorna a parte a direita por padrão, ao passar o terceiro argumento como true o retorno é a parte a esquerda.

```
$link = '13542345/essa_e_minhastring';
echo strstr($link, '/', true);
```

Outra opção é [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), ela transforma a string em um array, basta pegar o primeiro elemento(indice zero).

Essa sintaxe funciona a partir do 5.4

```
$link = '13542345/essa_e_minhastring';
$numero = explode('/', $link)[0];
echo $numero;
```

para versões inferiores faça:

```
$link = '13542345/essa_e_minhastring';
$numero = explode('/', $link);
echo $numero[0];
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/6bzK87)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, a sua também está correta, escolhi a resposta anterior pois foi postada primeiro.

Comment: +1 Agora sim [;)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/89513/revisions)

Comment: @Bacco tem muito código em php que é orientado a array haha as vezes acaba pegando alguns vicios.

Answer (score 7):

Use a função substr();

Ela pega o conteúdo até a barra e continua como string;

```
$text = "123456/efineinfe";
$text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, "/"));
```

Comment: +1 pelo caminho mais simples e direto, utilizando funções básicas de _string_ em vez de operações mais "caras". Só fique atento para não incluir informações supérfluas na resposta, nem dados pessoais que não digam respeito ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @Bacco estava a testar variantes diferentes e `preg_match` [parece ser a mais rápida](https://ideone.com/czHgSW). Podes dar uma olhada?

Comment: @Sergio complicado medir nesse caso, pq pode ser que o preg_match esteja fazendo cache da expressão e reutilizando, ganhando velocidade da 2a iteração em diante (isto é apenas uma teoria).

Comment: @Bacco sim, mesmo colocando a declaração da expressão dentro do loop dá-me [mais rápido](https://ideone.com/6uMh1V). Mas sim, verdade, é caso demasiado isolado para ter certezas.

Comment: @Sergio o número de operações internas de uma compilação de RegEx é muito maior do que o de uma busca de substring, em compensação a execução é rápida por se transformar em uma state machine na maior parte das implementações, mas como é PHP, complicado confiar na implementação de qq uma das 2 coisas :P

Comment: Isso mesmo, não é uma verificação precisa e nem tão confiável assim.